# NLTK: Package Errors? punkt and pickle?

Tags: python, command-line, package, nlp, nltk

[image: Errors on Command Prompt]

Basically, I have no idea why I'm getting this error.

Just to have more than an image, here is a similar message in code format. As it is more recent, the answer of this thread has already been mentioned in the message:

```
Preprocessing raw texts ...

---------------------------------------------------------------------------

LookupError                               Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-38-263240bbee7e> in <module>()
----> 1 main()

7 frames

<ipython-input-32-62fa346501e8> in main()
     32     data = data.fillna('')  # only the comments has NaN's
     33     rws = data.abstract
---> 34     sentences, token_lists, idx_in = preprocess(rws, samp_size=samp_size)
     35     # Define the topic model object
     36     #tm = Topic_Model(k = 10), method = TFIDF)

<ipython-input-31-f75213289788> in preprocess(docs, samp_size)
     25     for i, idx in enumerate(samp):
     26         sentence = preprocess_sent(docs[idx])
---> 27         token_list = preprocess_word(sentence)
     28         if token_list:
     29             idx_in.append(idx)

<ipython-input-29-eddacbfa6443> in preprocess_word(s)
    179     if not s:
    180         return None
--> 181     w_list = word_tokenize(s)
    182     w_list = f_punct(w_list)
    183     w_list = f_noun(w_list)

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/nltk/tokenize/__init__.py in word_tokenize(text, language, preserve_line)
    126     :type preserver_line: bool
    127     """
--> 128     sentences = [text] if preserve_line else sent_tokenize(text, language)
    129     return [token for sent in sentences
    130             for token in _treebank_word_tokenizer.tokenize(sent)]

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/nltk/tokenize/__init__.py in sent_tokenize(text, language)
     92     :param language: the model name in the Punkt corpus
     93     """
---> 94     tokenizer = load('tokenizers/punkt/{0}.pickle'.format(language))
     95     return tokenizer.tokenize(text)
     96 

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/nltk/data.py in load(resource_url, format, cache, verbose, logic_parser, fstruct_reader, encoding)
    832 
    833     # Load the resource.
--> 834     opened_resource = _open(resource_url)
    835 
    836     if format == 'raw':

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/nltk/data.py in _open(resource_url)
    950 
    951     if protocol is None or protocol.lower() == 'nltk':
--> 952         return find(path_, path + ['']).open()
    953     elif protocol.lower() == 'file':
    954         # urllib might not use mode='rb', so handle this one ourselves:

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/nltk/data.py in find(resource_name, paths)
    671     sep = '*' * 70
    672     resource_not_found = '\n%s\n%s\n%s\n' % (sep, msg, sep)
--> 673     raise LookupError(resource_not_found)
    674 
    675 

LookupError: 
**********************************************************************
  Resource punkt not found.
  Please use the NLTK Downloader to obtain the resource:

  >>> import nltk
  >>> nltk.download('punkt')
  
  Searched in:
    - '/root/nltk_data'
    - '/usr/share/nltk_data'
    - '/usr/local/share/nltk_data'
    - '/usr/lib/nltk_data'
    - '/usr/local/lib/nltk_data'
    - '/usr/nltk_data'
    - '/usr/lib/nltk_data'
    - ''
**********************************************************************
```

Comment: Read the stuff in between the `********************`s. Open up a Python shell, `import nltk`, and then run `nltk.download()`.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/30822962/610569

Comment: The image should have been formatted as code.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Perform the following:

```
>>> import nltk
>>> nltk.download()
```

Then when you receive a window popup, select `punkt` under the `identifier` column which is locatedin the `Module` tab.

[image]

Comment: So I have tried this in the python shell, but it says "No module nltk," which I know I did install

Comment: Did it say that after `import nltk`?

Comment: It did, but I figured out that nltk needed to be updated first, then the rest worked. Thank you!

Comment: What about production environment? I mean, works fine locally, but what if I need to deploy to AWS using GitHub actions for CICD? Need to add something to the workflow file (.yml), or the Dockerfile maybe?

Answer (score 9):

**Do**:

```
>>> import nltk
>>> nltk.download('punkt')
>>> from nltk import sent_tokenize
```

**To download all dataset and models**:

```
>>> nltk.download('all')
```

Ensure that you've the latest version of `NLTK` because it's always improving and constantly maintain:

```
$ pip install --upgrade nltk
```

---

**Similar question on Windows/Linux but with the above code snippet don't help**:

- [error installing nltk supporting packages : nltk.download()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27750608/error-installing-nltk-supporting-packages-nltk-download)
- [Python nltk download and download_shell both freeze (hang) on punkt attempt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21194895/python-nltk-download-and-download-shell-both-freeze-hang-on-punkt-attempt)
- [Proxy error while downloading NLTK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28454508/proxy-error-while-downloading-nltk)
- [NLTK Wordnet Download Out of Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21366286/nltk-wordnet-download-out-of-date)
- [NLTK and Stopwords Fail #lookuperror](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26693736/nltk-and-stopwords-fail-lookuperror)
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/527388/python-nltk-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts-nltk-downloadbrown-results-in-html-error-40

**Similar question on Windows**:

- [NLTK and Stopwords Fail #lookuperror](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26693736/nltk-and-stopwords-fail-lookuperror)

**Similar question on Linux platform**:

- [downloading error using nltk.download()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27658409/downloading-error-using-nltk-download)
- [How do I download NLTK data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22211525/how-do-i-download-nltk-data)
- [Failed loading english.pickle with nltk.data.load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4867197/failed-loading-english-pickle-with-nltk-data-load)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29206471/downloading-nltk-corpora-for-python-3-4
  -

**Similar question on OSX**:

- [nltk.download() hangs on OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16598830/nltk-download-hangs-on-os-x)

**Similar question but has some authorization/authentication errors**:

- [nltk download url authorization issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25998742/nltk-download-url-authorization-issue)
- [nltk.download() failed with the http error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28773122/nltk-download-failed-with-the-http-error)
- [HTTP: Proxy Authentification Error for nltk.download()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17672423/http-proxy-authentification-error-for-nltk-download)
  -

**Similar question that tries to install NLTK data outside of python interpreter**:

- [Installing nltk data in setup.py script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26799894/installing-nltk-data-in-setup-py-script)

Answer (score 2):

To pre-install the punkt package with a single command line `python -c 'import nltk; nltk.download("punkt")'`.